# Violation of Cauchy's Integral Theorem [Solved]

Tags: complex-analysis

I got a question. If I calculate: $$\oint_{|z|=1}\overline{z}\;\mathrm{d}z$$The result is $2\pi\mathrm{i}$ and not $0$. Why does this not violate the Cauchy integral theorem? A hint should be all I need, but currently I'm out of ideas.

edit: thanks for all the quick replies that $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ is not an analytic function

Comment: Read each word of the integral theorem carefully, and maybe you'll spot it.

Comment: $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is not analytic.

Comment: JINX!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The theorem states:

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $C$ which is simply connected, let $f : U → C$ be a **holomorphic function**, and let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable path in $U$ whose start point is equal to its end point. Then
> $$\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=0$$

---

> If $\bar z=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=x-iy$ doesnt satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\tag{1}$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\tag{2}$$ then $\bar z$ is not holomorphic.

Answer (score -1):

Because conjugation is *not* an analytic function.